# Permission set does not exist in process builder

Tags: process-builder, permission-sets, system-permissions, automated-process

I am facing a problem while creating a process with process builder, i want to call a permission set but i cannot find it , can someone help me
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with the difference between `Permission` and `Permission Set`.

In your screenshot, you usually search for a Permission `Setup --> Custom Code --> Custom Permissions` and not a `Permission Set`.

Your user can gain such permission in these cases:

- The user has a profile that contains that custom permission
- The user has a Permission set assigned that contains that custom permission
- The user has a Permission set group that has a permission set as the one before.

So if you want to see something in the list of your screenshot, make sure you have a `Custom Permission` with what you are looking for ;)

Comment: thank you it worked